# How to update a record in large file that contains special characters in linux using sed command?

Tags: linux, sed, special-characters

I have test.psv file that contains some records with special characters

i.e.:

```
123|account|"Term"|Temp A/C form's|2023-07-30|Book & Print|AR ACTEVOL,DR|PORT SC ACTIONSEVOL, PR|123
```

I need to remove the special characters in the above record and replace it with

```
123|account|"Term"|Temp A/C form's|2023-07-30|Book & Print|AR ACTEVOL,DR|PORT SC ACTIONSEVOL, PR|123
```

How would I be able to do this in Linux environment with sed command? Please assist.

I tried the following:

```bash
sed -i 's\123|account|"Term"|Temp A/C form's|2023-07-30|Book & Print|AR ACTEVOL,DR|PORT SC ACTIONSEVOL, PR|123\123|account|"Term"|Temp A/C form's|2023-07-30|Book & Print|AR ACTEVOL,DR|PORT SC ACTIONSEVOL, PR|123\g' file.psv
```

and it gave me errors.

N.B.: there was a special character "Á" in 'AR ACTÁEVOL,DR and I wanted to replace the line without the 'Á' Somehow in my post, the special character was missed, when I posted. The special character was a box. Grep didn't return either.

Comment: there was a special character "Á" in 'AR ACTÁEVOL,DR and I wanted to replace the line without the 'Á'

Somehow in my post, the special character was missed, when I posted. The special character was a box. Grep didn't return either.

Comment: Is the input UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, or some other encoding?

Comment: What is your definition of "special character"? It doesn't seem to match the tag you have chosen.

Comment: You might be better to use `iconv`, `uconv`, or `recode`

Comment: cf. https://youtu.be/_mZBa3sqTrI for some transliteration pitfalls

Comment: the proximate cause of your errors will be that single-quotes cannot appear inside single-quoted strings. `'a'b'c'` is not `a'b'c` inside quotes, it is `a` followed by `b`(unquoted), followed by `c`

Comment: @jhnc, its UTF-8

Comment: this was the special character or some icons..